# select tag after js.erb render :prompt=>'Select Genre' not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
<%= select_tag "select_genre_manage_audio", options_from_collection_for_select(@music_genre, :id, :name), :prompt=>'Select Genre',:id=>'select_genre_manage_audio',:class=>'select_genre_manage_audio', :style=>"  width: 400px;" %>
in js.erb file i do 
$('#select_genre_manage_audio').html('<%= escape_javascript options_from_collection_for_select(@select_genre_manage_audio,:id,:name),:prompt=>'Select Genre' %>')
```

Here prompt not working , Why?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by doing this

e.g

```
$('#select_genre_manage_audio').html('<%= escape_javascript options_for_select({"Select Genre", ""}) + options_from_collection_for_select(@select_genre_manage_audio,:id,:name)   %>')
```